# Padding between UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

There is some left and right padding between `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`. I have overridden the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods for insets and I am returning `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Still there is left and right padding. Please point me to the right direction.

**Edit #1**

[image]

Left and right side have padding.

Comment: Have you given proper `Leading` and `Trailing` to `UICollectionView `?

Comment: check your itemSize (the size of the cell).

Comment: Can you update your question by adding the Screenshot for the results you are seeing?

Comment: Does your collection view has any leading or trailing constraints?

Comment: No the collectionview does not have leading or trailing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for padding in collectionView.  Its working fine for me

Manage Cell Spacing and set delegate as UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let padding: CGFloat =  10
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 118)

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
```

Comment: I dont have grid . Its like a list view. so i am not setting the size using the Flowlayout delegate method

Answer (score 0):

See Collection view properties in Size Inspector on right side of this image. 
I hope it will help you

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: All the things have 0 values. If i increase it is adding more padding

Comment: You want padding or you want to remove padding?

Comment: From your question it seems you want padding b/w cells and collection view boundary

Comment: I want to remove that padding from left and right. I have designed the collection view cell in xcode visual editor there it is not showing any padding

Comment: Then problem is not with your collectionview and cell, but with you haven't managed AutoLayout or AutoResizing, search for these terms in google it will help you to understand iOS Views

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the code as follows and let us know, if that works.
First define *sectionInsets* in *YourViewController*

```
 fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

and then implement the DelegateFlowLayout.

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let paddingSpace = 2 * (itemsPerRow - 1)
    let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow

    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
}
}
```